# Copy directories and files with ProgressBar

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, console-application

Trying to create a console application to copy directories from the source to the destination and either the progress bar does nothing while files are copied...

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(source, destination)

For i = 1 To 100
    Console.Write(String.Format("Copy progress: {0}%" & vbCr, i))
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
Next
```

or the ProgressBar says "Copy Progress 1%" the entire time it's copying...

```
For i = 1 To 100
    Console.Write(String.Format("Copy progress: {0}%" & vbCr, i))
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(source, destination)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
Next
```

Wondering what I am doing wrong because I am obviously putting the My.Computer line in the wrong spot!

Comment: You will have to copy the files one at a time and increment the progress after each one has copied. The `CopyDirectory` method does it all before passing control onto the next instruction, so it it not suitable for this purpose.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank You for your response is there something better to use other then CopyDirectory?

Comment: Once you have obtained a list of the files with the [Directory.GetFiles Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use the [File.Copy Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) to copy each one. You may find it the [Path.Combine Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) useful for putting parts of paths together reliably.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It says destination is a directory and not a file.

Comment: You have to tell it the full path to the destination file, *including* the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution, using Linq `Select` to copy the file list returned by [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles)

Pass the sample method an array of Source Directories and a Destination Directory.
The progress (0-100%) is printed to the Output window, and a ProgressBar gives a visual feedback of the copy status for each Source Path.

This method will return the list of all files copied.

[image]

```
Dim sourcePath As String() = New String() {"[SourcePath1]", "[SourcePath2]", "[SourcePath3]"}
Dim destinationPath As String = "[DestinationPath]"
Dim filesCopied As List(Of String) = CopyDirectoryWithProgress(sourcePath, destinationPath)
Console.ReadLine()

Private Function CopyDirectoryWithProgress(sourcePath As String(), destPath As String) As List(Of String)

    Dim allFilesCopied As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Dim progressBarPassSymbol As Char = ChrW(&H25A0)
    Dim progressBarEmptySymbol As String = New String(ChrW(&H2014), 30)

    For Each sPath As String In sourcePath
        Dim fileInfo As New DirectoryInfo(sPath).GetFiles()
        Dim numberOfFiles As Integer = fileInfo.Length - 1
        Dim progressBarPass As Double = (30 / numberOfFiles)
        Dim increment As Double = 100 / numberOfFiles
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath)

        Console.CursorLeft = 0
        Console.Write("Copy progress: ")
        Console.CursorLeft = 20
        Console.Write(progressBarEmptySymbol)

        allFilesCopied.AddRange(fileInfo.
            Select(Function(f, i)
               File.Copy(Path.Combine(sPath, f.Name), Path.Combine(destPath, f.Name), True)
               Console.CursorLeft = 15
               Console.Write("{0:g}% " &
                   New String(progressBarPassSymbol, CInt((i + 1) * progressBarPass)),
                   CInt((i + 1) * increment))

               Return f.FullName
           End Function))
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
    Return allFilesCopied
End Function
```

For an interesting method to perform this task with a much faster file enumerator, see this CodeProject article: [A Faster Directory Enumerator](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38959/A-Faster-Directory-Enumerator)

Comment: No, It Works! now I am trying to make the `SourcePath` to an array to hold 3 different paths. i.e. `Dim SourcePath() As String = {"C:\Users\username\Desktop", "D:\", "E:\"}`

Comment: oh yes, please!

Comment: I tried running that and it just goes into break mode?

Comment: how can I send you a DM?

Comment: DM = Direct Message

Comment: not really a coding question, but was trying to get ideas of other things I can do with console applications

Comment: @bckelley  Well, there's the [SO chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) for that. Now you have enough reputation to talk there. Btw, you never said if this code finally worked for you.

Comment: yea it works good enough...I always find things that I would do differently...so it will never be done

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the Windows built-in progress bar when copying using the UIOption.AllDialogs:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\text.txt", "C:\my_folder\text.txt", FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
```